# foreach loop and select statment

Tags: php, mysql

The foreach loop never displays the link but if I remove my SELECT statement the $key displays, which can be seen here: http://www.rotaryswing.com/swingviewer/videos.php

I am trying to create the link dynamically based on the IDs which in my foreach loop below are identified as $key.

Displaying all the information works fine. All the source code for this can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/hkC4L9UQ

I understand this is not the way i should store data but my knowledge lacks in how to do this any other way.

The IDs are inserted into the Db into an array using implode then comma separated. I then explode them like so:

echoing the key by itself works fine as expected.

```
//convert video id array to single lines
$pieces = explode(",", $video_ids);



//iterate through video IDS in our DB
foreach ($pieces as $key) {
    echo $key;  



$query4 ="SELECT id, video_name, link, phase FROM videos WHERE id=$key";
if ($stmt4 = $mysqli->prepare($query4)) {
$stmt4->execute();  
/* bind result variables */
$stmt4->bind_result($id, $vid_name, $vid_link, $phase);
/* fetch values */
while ($stmt4->fetch()) {
echo "<a href='http://www.rotaryswing.com/golf-instruction/video  /rst-index.php?cat=$phase&subcat=Rotary%20Swing%20Tour&video=$id&id=$vid_link&name=$vid_name' target=\"blank\">" .$vid_name. "</a><br>";

 }

 }
 }
```

You will notice the video IDs in sets of three numbers on this page. Evrything else works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not working. I need help getting it to work..

Comment: "Not working" is not a helpful diagnosis.

Comment: Remember to use [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to supply values like `$key` before executing. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You should format your code properly, use PDO, and ask a proper question. In this case, you should say what your expected result is, and what you're actually getting, along with providing the code, as you have, of what you've tried.

Comment: Yea I was trying to degub stuff and just added that there. I do use bind_params throughout my code as can be seen in my PasteBin post above

Comment: Note that putting comma separated lists (or any lists, for that matter) into a relational database violates the first rule of relation database design. Research "normalization", specifically the first normal form (1NF).

Comment: PDO is not a requirement. I chose Procedural style and that's that. PDo does not mean right. It means choice

Comment: Again not my question. I not this but unfortunately I am adding multiple checkbox inputs to the database and refuse to have 900 columns if some so chooses to check all of them. instead I chose to make an array of the ids and then explode them and iterate through db to get the required info. But it is not working.

Comment: all code IS provided via Pastebin link. I did ask my question. Thanks again..

Comment: Putting 900 columns for the options would also violate the 1NF. - What you do is create another table for the options and link it to the first one. Not going to go into this too much here though, since this is off topic, but you should do some reading into this if you are doing DB design.

Comment: why am I getting down votes? this is a legit problem I am having and I literally provided everything but the DB itself

Comment: if you do one thing wrong (formatting wise) these people will crucify you, it sucks man, as you have seen. One thing I always recommend is printing out all of your variables involved and make sure they are all getting the proper values. If nothing is coming up in your foreach then $stmt4->fetch() is probably empty.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you're basically expecting people to do your work. Few people are going spend their time reading through all your code on pastebin and figuring out where the problem is. Isolate the code that's failing, post that code (and clean up the formatting please), show us what you've done to debug it. Also clearly explain what the expected results are. FYI I didn't downvote.

Comment: I did isolate dude... I showed it above... it is Above.. My other code works fine as stated.. you didn't read my post obviously. It is a simple issue that I probably overlooked something, which with answer provided below I did just miss something. I provided the pastebin as reference..lol jeez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing about that code that would make this hard to figure out is that you are ignoring the success of the query execution, and assuming that it's successful. The `$stmt4->execute()` returns a boolean indicating whether or not it was in fact successful. You should be checking that and, if it fails, logging/printing the error.

```
//convert video id array to single lines
$pieces = explode(",", $video_ids);

//iterate through video IDS in our DB
foreach ($pieces as $key) {
    $sql ="SELECT id, video_name, link, phase FROM videos WHERE id=?";
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $key);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $vid_name, $vid_link, $phase);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='$id'  value='$id' />";
                echo "<a href='http://www.rotaryswing.com/golf-instruction/video  /rst-index.php?cat=$phase&subcat=Rotary%20Swing%20Tour&video=$id&id=$vid_link&name=$vid_name' target=\"blank\">$vid_name</a><br>";
            }
        }
        else {
            trigger_error("SQL query failed: " . $stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if the query fails for some reason, this will either log or print the error, depending on your server settings.

Also note two things. First, I'm using a parametrized query there, which prevents SQL injection. Second, I've intended the code in a sane manner, making this far easier to read than your code.

Comment: Thanks for a response. I will test this and see what my issue is

Comment: hmm.. this works but only shows one result when I have two I know exist.. Any way to show all results using this code you provided?

Comment: Have you checked the `$pieces` array to make sure it has all the IDs you are expecting? This code snippet just shows you the videos in that list, so if you are only getting one, and no error, then it would seem only one is being returned. Use the `var_dump` function to find out what the variables contain. - Also, make sure error reporting is enabled. Otherwise the SQL error will not be printed.

Comment: there has to be an error somewhere else. I will figure it out. Most people here are douches. Either they think I did not write it or they think some other weird shit.

Comment: SO is a very Q&A oriented site. People expect very clear questions that can result in very clear answers. Discussion isn't really encouraged by the SO style of forum sites. This can be either a very good, or very bad, thing, depending on your needs. - If you want help working through your problem, as opposed to getting specific answers to specific questions, you may have better luck on a more traditional "forum" site.

Comment: I figured it out. thanks. Just now the string [0] is skipped in the for each.